# Visual Studio build go slower after adding fontawesome svgs

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2013

After adding fontawesome svg files, I noticed that the build (run) was going slower, so I practically needed about 5 minutes to compile the code. And this creates a big problem for me as I'm still in development so I frequently change the code.

For the files configuration, I have:

1. **Build action:** Content.
2. **Copy to output directory:** Copy if newer.

I think Visual Studio needs some time to check each file whether it exists or not, but I'm not sure. Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a little work around that works great for me. There was no need to add files to Visual Studio and then set the build action and output directory to practically **+10000** svg files. the trick was to just copy the fontawesome folder to the bin directory.